# padding in tf.data.Dataset in tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets, language-translation, data-pipeline

Code:

```
a=training_dataset.map(lambda x,y: (tf.pad(x,tf.constant([[13-int(tf.shape(x)[0]),0],[0,0]])),y))
```

gives the following error:

```
TypeError: in user code:

<ipython-input-32-b25101c2110a>:1 None  *
    a=training_dataset.map(lambda x,y: (tf.pad(tensor=x,paddings=tf.constant([[13-int(tf.shape(x)[0]),0],[0,0]]),mode="CONSTANT"),y))
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py:264 constant  **
    allow_broadcast=True)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py:282 _constant_impl
    allow_broadcast=allow_broadcast))
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py:456 make_tensor_proto
    _AssertCompatible(values, dtype)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py:333 _AssertCompatible
    raise TypeError("Expected any non-tensor type, got a tensor instead.")

TypeError: Expected any non-tensor type, got a tensor instead.
```

However, when I use:

```
a=training_dataset.map(lambda x,y: (tf.pad(x,tf.constant([[1,0],[0,0]])),y))
```

Above code works fine.
This brings me to the conclusion that something is wrong with: `13-tf.shape(x)[0]` but cannot understand what.
I tried converting the `tf.shape(x)[0]` to `int(tf.shape(x)[0])` and still got the same error.

What I want the code to do:
I have a `tf.data.Dataset` object having variable length sequences of size `(None,128)` where the first dimension(None) is less than 13. I want to pad the sequences such that the size of every collection is 13  i.e `(13,128)`.
Is there any alternate way (if the above problem cannot be solved)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution that works:

using:

`paddings = tf.concat(([[13-tf.shape(x)[0],0]], [[0,0]]), axis=0)`

instead of using:

`paddings = tf.constant([[13-tf.shape(x)[0],0],[0,0]])`

works for me.
However, I still cannot figure out why the latter one did not work.